# Transferring repository ownership to organization

Tags: github

We have a private repository on GitHub for our company's project. Initially i started off the repository, therefore current owner is me. But as the team grew we started to feel an urge to create a organization on GitHub which enables roles etc.

Current situation:

- several distinct development machines are connected to the repository
  by ['personal access tokens'](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token). So their authentication is cached globally.
- Live (production) server that is connected to the repository, with an ['SSH key'](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/about-ssh) .
- Test (development) server also connected to the repository. But it asks for authentication each time (username and password/[PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token))

In this case, if a transfer the ownership of the repository from my account to company's organization: what I'll possibly break ? I've read that GitHub will redirect old URL to the repository will point to the new URL. But still, i think SSH key on the live server is likely to fail.

Can you please inform me about possible outcomes ? Thank you.

Edit 1: Results

Here is the results if anyone stumbles upon this post.

- Old remote URL worked just fine, as stated in GitHub docs on transferring ownership. But we decided it's for the best to change the remote URL to new one, just in case.
- Development machines with [PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) worked just fine. No issue has been encountered.
- We updated Live (production) server's origin remote URL right away so there won't be any funny business. SSH key had to be updated to comfort the new URL.
- Test is still using old URL without any issue.

Comment: Everything about this question is specific to GitHub: the answers would be different for other web hosting sites. To get the answers, you probably should use the GitHub help pages and/or talk to the GitHub support folks. (Meanwhile I trimmed off other tags.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, personal access tokens work based on the owner's access permissions, so if you continue to retain access to the repository, then those will continue to work.  The same is true of SSH keys associated with the account.  Similarly, other users who have their own PATs or SSH keys and continue to retain access will have those PATs or keys continue to work.

Ideally for most automated system purposes, you'll want to use SSH with deploy keys, because those are associated with the repository, so if someone leaves the company, things won't break.  If you need to have individual users log into a server and pull, just have them forward their SSH agent.

If you need PATs for automated processes, such as for making API calls, you'll want to make a bot account and grant it access to the repository.  That's much easier than trying to use individual people's PATs and again, it prevents employees who leave the company from breaking things when they lose access.

Comment: Transfer will take place soon, I'll comment down below actual outcomes. Thanks